# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException when running arduino on bash (via Windows subsystem of Linux)

Tags: java, arduino, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been running WSL for a short time now, and I've been trying to compile and upload Arduino scripts via this console.

I installed arduino by running `sudo apt install arduino` but from there whenever I run any arduino command (even simply `arduino`) I get the following exception

I've tried installing the Linux Arduino IDE via this command line but had no effect. My assumption is this is a problem originating for WSL and arduino not being designed for that environment

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at arduinopc.<init>(arduinopc.java:35)
    at arduinopc$3.run(arduinopc.java:85)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processing.app.Preferences.setColor(Preferences.java:851)
    at processing.app.Preferences.init(Preferences.java:273)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:117)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask(HeadlessToolkit.java:236)
    at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The Windows Linux subsystem is only for commandline applications not for running GUI apps.

Arelatively simple alternative is to get VirtualBox or QEmu for Windows and start / install a small linux distribution.

If it's only the Arduino IDE that you want to run then you don't need that either because it is also available for Windows:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Answer (score 1):

This Exception occurs also using OpenJDK. 
I changed java from OpenJDK to Java(TM) and the application is running without exception.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)


/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino IDE is a typically used as a GUI, which is not supported by your WLS, hence the error message:

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

However, command line operation of the Arduino IDE was added in Arduino IDE 1.5.2, which does allow many operations to be done from the console (see https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc). Originally this required you to run a virtual frame buffer but that is no longer necessary with the last few releases of the Arduino IDE.

> I installed arduino by running sudo apt install arduino

When you do that you get a very outdated and possibly non-standard version of the Arduino IDE which does not support command line usage. Due to licensing documentation [issues](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/2703), it has not been possible to update the version of the Arduino IDE available via the package managers. You should always install the Arduino IDE by downloading the latest version from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software. Once you have done that you will be able to use the command line feature.